# How to handle zero rows returned when binding data to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I'm populating a DGV with data from a database and everything works fine, with the exception of when 0 rows are returned to the DataTable that populates the DGV. And I'm not sure how exactly to handle that situation, which I do need to allow for due to the program requirements.

Here's the Form code that calls the data binding method:

```
public void PopulateDgvCategories()
{
    string companyFilter = cboSelectCompany.Text;
    string categoryFilter = cboSelectCategory.Text;

    db categoriesData = new db();

    if (categoryFilter == "All Categories")
    {
        string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 " +
                            "FROM masterfiles.xref WHERE company_name = @company ORDER BY category, old_value";
           this.dtCategories = categoriesData.GetDgvData(catsQuery, companyFilter, categoryFilter);
    }
    else
    {
        string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 " +
                            "FROM masterfiles.xref WHERE company_name = @company and category = @category ORDER BY old_value";
        this.dtCategories = categoriesData.GetDgvData(catsQuery, companyFilter, categoryFilter);
    }

    // Need to check this.dtCategories.Rows.Count
    //  If 0, then need to figure out how to handle that

    dgvCategories.DataSource = this.dtCategories;

    dgvCategories.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    dgvCategories.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
}
```

And here's how I'm retrieving the data and filling the DataTable:

```
public DataTable GetDgvData(string selectQuery, string companyFilter, string categoryFilter)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("company", companyFilter));
        if (categoryFilter != "All Categories") cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("category", categoryFilter));

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();

        using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        conn.Close();

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

It is possible for the `categoryFilter` variable to cause the query to return 0 rows.

What is the best way to handle that? I'm thinking manually create the DGV with just the header row (column names) and display a MessageBox saying no rows were returned. Is that possible/feasible and would it be the best way to handle that?

Comment: Since `da.Fill(ds);` returns the number of Rows added, you could modify your `GetDgvData()` to return this value (returning a tuple `(DataTable, int)` or `ref` parameter) or using the returned DataTable to check how many rows it contains. If it's `0`, don't execute code that touches the DGV's cells.

Comment: Use Count : if(this.dtCategories.Count() > 0)

Comment: "I'm thinking manually create the DGV with just the header row (column names)"? Ok, I'm not familiar with the Npgsql provider, but are you saying that the `da.Fill` command is not filling the DataTable schema (the Columns) when no rows are returned?  An empty table with a schema can be assigned  as a DGV datasource for automatic column creation, there just will not be as rows to display.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I'm thinking along the "empty table" route. Others have mentioned how to check for 0 rows, and I was thinking I could add a TableLayoutPanel the same size as the DGV, with the headers in the TLP to look like the headers in a populated DGV. Then load the form with the Table hiddden and show it (and hide the DGV) when there are no rows to return. Presentation-wise it could look seamless to the user if done right. Thoughts?

Comment: You are risking getting your question closed by asking for opinions. That said, I would use a SplitContainer control with Orientation=Horizontal.  Panel1 would house a fully docked DGV. Panel2 would house a Label fully docked with AutoSize=false and TextAlign=MiddleCenter.  After you assign the DGV datasource, set the SplitContainer SplitterDistance = dgv.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty).Height and `SplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = dt.Rows.Count > 0`.  Set the Label's text to whatever message you want to display.

Comment: Thanks, @TnTinMn I'll take a look at that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem binding a datatable with zero rows - it will have a set of columns of the correct types regardless and will autocreate columns if the AutoGenerateColumns property is true

The problems come simply because you're trying to access a datagridview cell at 0,0 without making sure it exists, so you *could* put:

```
dgvCategories.DataSource = this.dtCategories;
dgvCategories.Columns[0].Visible = false;

it(dtCategories.Rows.Count > 0)
  dgvCategories.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
```

**But** you should just take this line out completely - it doesn't do anything anyway; it doesn't hide the blue selection highlight in the top left and a freshly bound datagridview's top left cell is already `Selected=false` so you're not achieving anything other than an exception with this line of code

[image]

If you want to hide the blue selection highlight when a DGV isn't focused, set the cell's `Style.SelectionBackColor` to be the same as its `Style.BackColor`, but do set it to something visible when the user focuses the grid or they will struggle to understand why they can't make that cell highlighted.

If you want to remove the ghost row that allows you to add new values, set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false

If you want to let the user know there were no rows from a recent search, place a label on top of the DGV with a "Your search 'whatever' returned no results" and set its visibility depending on whether there are rows:

```
lblNoResults.Text = $"Your search '{categoryFilter}' returned no rows";
lblNoResults.Visible = dtCategories.Rows.Count == 0;
```

Finally, you don't need to use a DataSet when all you want is a DataTable. A datadapter can fill a datatable; there is no need to go to the extra wasted effort of using a dataset - it's like using a `List<string>` and accessing it's 0th element when all you want is a `string`. You also don't need to open/close the connection - dataadapter knows how to do this itself. It is intelligent enough to not close a connection opened elsewhere (in case there is a transaction in progress):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTale();
    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
```

Comment: Wow! Great points, and thanks for taking the time to go through all of that - especially since much of it wasn't directly asked in my question!